# When should I activate Man Lands and Keyrunes in order to attack with them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some lands and artifacts have abilities which allow them to be animated, and turned into creatures until end of turn. Examples include [Inkmoth Nexus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Inkmoth%20Nexus), [Blinkmoth Nexus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blinkmoth%20Nexus), [Azorious Keyrune](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorious%20Keyrune), [Treetop Village](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Treetop%20Village) and several others. These abilities can be activated at any time, and  then those permanents can be used to attack that turn.

**At what point during the turn should abilities that animate non-creatures be activated so that they can attack?**

Comment: Question has been downvoted - can anyone tell me what I need to improve?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. You're currently at 1 upvote, 0 downvotes. Maybe someone undid an upvote?

Comment: someone undid a downvote - i guess it was intended for my answer rather than for the question

Comment: Re "and then those permanents can be used to attack that turn", I don't know why you mentioned this. It makes it sound like they aren't subject to summoning sickness, but they are. If the permanent hasn't been under your control since the beginning of your most recent turn, it can't attack (unless it has haste).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should activate them at some point before the declare attackers step on a turn after they enter the battlefield (unless they have haste).

Here's a breakdown of the declare attackers step:

> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers.
>
> 508.2. Second, any abilities that triggered on attackers being declared go on the stack.
>
> 508.3. Third, the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities.

Clearly, during the declare attackers step, it is too late to activate the abilities (508.3) in order to make them attackers (508.1). However, you are free to do so during your upkeep, first main phase, and beginning of Combat step and it will be eligible to attack.

Note that if you cast a keyrune and turn it into a creature, it cannot attack. This is because permanents that are creatures are unable to attack or use activated abilities with the tap symbol in them unless they have been under their owners control continuously since their most recent turn began (302.6).

It could still be tapped for mana if it is not a creature but as soon as you turn it into a creature it can no longer be tapped to activate abilities the turn it comes into play.

With regards to shortcuts, according to the

> A statement such as "I'm ready for combat" or "Declare attackers?" offers to keep passing priority
> until an opponent has priority in the beginning of combat step. **Opponents are assumed to be acting
> then unless they specify otherwise.**

In other words, the following exchanges between Aaron the Attacker and Dave the Defender, officiated by Jerry the Judge, have different outcomes

### Scenario 1

> Aaron: Attacks? *long pause*
>
> Dave: *nods head*
>
> Aaron: I activate my keyrune and swing with him for 2.
>
> Dave: Judge!
>
> Jerry: Sorry Aaron, because you passed priority with your "Attacks?" comment, your keyrune was activated too late to be an attacker.

### Scenario 2

> Aaron: Attacks - I activate my keyrune. *long pause*
>
> Dave: *nods head*
>
> Aaron: I swing with him for 2.
>
> Dave: I take 2, I'm at 18 life.
>
> Jerry: I'm going to sip this margarita because I'm not needed here. *sips margarita*

Comment: In hindsight, judges should probably not be drinking while on active judge duty.

Answer (score -2):

**Update**

Having discussed the below with several local judges, it has been made clear that the below would actually be a very totalitarian view for a judge to take, and as long as you state clearly your intentions you probably will still get to activate your man land.

The correct time to activate man lands is any point during your turn before the declare attackers step, as has been mentioned in other answers. As an addendum, **being extremely clear about where you are in the turn when you are activating them is key in tournament play. Better safe than sorry!**

---

The main parts of the turn relevant to this question are:

some of the sub steps are omitted, as they are not relevant.

- Beginning Phase
- Main Phase
- Combat Phase

  - Beginning of Combat step
  - Declare Attackers step
  - Declare Blockers step
  - Damage step
  - End of Combat step

When you are playing a game of magic, you are playing with/against **another person**. This is the key to the answer to this question, as while you are entitled to animate these permanents at any point before the **Declare Attackers step**, in a real game of magic,

**unless the active player explicitly passes priority in their main phase, to have priority in their beginning of combat step. the active player only has priority in their beginning of combat step if their opponent chooses to do something in that step**.

this is due to a **shortcut** listed in the rules, wherein the active player declares "attacks?" or "move to attack" or "combat" or some similar statement. This shortcut, in the literal sense, translates to "Pass priority up until you have priority in the Beginning of Combat step". The result of this shortcut is, if you move into the combat phase, you are automatically giving your opponent priority just before you declare attackers. If your opponent passes priority, the game moves to the **Declare Attackers step** and you have **missed your opportunity to animate**.

**The latest safe opportunity to animate your man lands, or other permanents that become creatures through activating an ability, is in the *First Main Phase*.** if you leave it until after this point, you are in the hands of your opponent and the judge staff for whether you get to activate the man land. If you cant demonstrate a good reason (for example, to empty some mana from your opponent's mana pool), they will probably not let you activate.

Source for this shortcut:
Tournament Procedure Guide - section 4.2, Bullet point 2

> A Statement such as "I'm Ready for combat", or "Declare attackers?" offers to keep passing priority until an opponent has priority in the beginning of combat step. Opponents are assumed to be acting then unless they specify otherwise

also covered in these articles

http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/article/20071109a

https://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=judge/article/20050204a

Comment: I'm sceptical of the claim that "you never have priority in your beginning of combat step" - it may be true, but can you back it up further?  With reference to the comprehensive rules on shortcuts etc, I guess I mean.

Comment: 507. Beginning of Combat Step ... 507.3. Third, the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities.

Comment: I believe it's incorrect actually. You get priority there. For example, you declare attacks, I can detain/kill/tap your creatures with instant speed abilities and spells during that step. If I detained your creature after it attacked (i.e. in my part of the declare attackers step) the creature would still be attacking.

Comment: Your point about the shortcuts is also misleading. There are no shortcuts officially listed in the rules. Shortcuts may be *suggested* in the rules, but shortcuts only officially exist between two players as mutually understood by those players. Those shortcuts may or may not be the same examples given by the rules.

Comment: There are 2 articles I just found on my phone explicitly defining this shortcut and explaining exactly why this is so well defined (i googled "mtg rules shortcuts", the top non-pdf results). the only way you are not taking this shortcut, is by EXPLICITLY passing priority in your mainphase to gain priority in your beginning of combat step. my point was you as the ACTIVE PLAYER never get priority in that step, unless your opponent does something, i will clarify that point in the answer and provide source material when i am able to access it on a computer and not just my phone

Comment: @corsiKa, please see my edit (and feel free to confirm in the document and look into it yourselves), this is an established shortcut, and both wizards mothership articles, and the Tournament Procedure guide explicitly lay out how it works.

Comment: There is nothing there that would say you don't ever get priority. You can easily tell your opponent(s) that you are going to begin your combat step and transform. They then have an opportunity to react before you declare attackers, but you always have the option of having priority. Furthermore the shortcut is a way of alerting your opponents that you plan to pass priority, not that you don't get it.

Comment: @Rawrgramming I did confirm: there are no established shortcuts. "716.1a The rules for taking shortcuts are largely unformalized. As long as each player in the game understands the intent of each other player, any shortcut system they use is acceptable."

Comment: true enough, if you explicitly pass priority in your main phase and ask if your opponent passes priority in your main phase, you can then activate your man lands in your beginning of combat step, but this serves no purpose, so the shortcut is assumed. If you try to do that in tournaments, you will get judges called, and you will get told you missed your chance 9 times out of 10. I am happy to modify my answer to make clear that activation during your mainphase is the "safest" option if that will make this a more acceptable answer.

Comment: @corsiKa, did you also check the document quoted in my answer, and read the articles i mentioned in a previous comment? note "largely" in the rule you quoted.

Comment: I feel like saying "Can I declare attackers?" might imply you want to skip the beginning of combat step, but that's a totally different thing from it being impossible for the active player ever to gain priority in the beginning of combat step...

Comment: Comments are not really a place for discussion. If you have more to say, consider moving it to chat.

Comment: @Rawrgramming maybe your opponent had floated some mana for whatever reason(like in response to you destroying a land), and you want that mana to be emptied from his pool before you animate your man-land

Comment: this is a good point, i have updated the answer to reflect that case, and to clarify that you can get priority, if you word it exactly. one of this changes the fact that you ought to as a rule activate during your mainphase in tournaments

Comment: for the record, I'll un-downvote when and only when your post no longer suggests that the first main phase is the latest point to activate your man-land

Comment: @Rawrgramming What you're saying here is that the commonly used shortcut goes to the declare attackers step. That's orthogonal to the question you actually asked, about activating these abilities. Clearly, the rules give you the choice to activate them during the beginning of combat step (for whatever reason). Yes, there are things you can say which translate to "I'm skipping over that step", but it seems you're being really eager to restate that as "you can't do anything in that step unless you can justify it to a judge."

Comment: Right, if you say "ok, I'm declaring attackers", then it's too late. If you say "Ok, at the beginning of combat step, I want to do this", then you can do it just fine.

Comment: For what it's worth, if someone said "attacks?" I would take it to mean "Let's move the game state to declare combat step and pass priority" not "Let's move the game state to declare attackers step". If they decline, it's because they want to take an action during their priority in the first main phase (or whatever phase we're on...).

Comment: i have further updated my answer to step back from the all or nothing approach i was taking, i left the majority of the text the same but made a clear update at the top. apologies for the kerfuffle!

Comment: @Rawrgramming I think your most recent info would be excellent as a new, separate answer. "Local judges said I should do this at Competitive REL, or this if I want to be absolutely safe" is **great** information to have. I feel like the other text confuses it, though.

Comment: @Rawrgramming After rereading your updated answer, I still find two significant errors. I addressed them in an edit to my answer containing two different scenarios, one of which happily ends with a drunk judge.

Comment: i think corsika's answer handles everything fully now. i am not sure how to word the additional answer you mentioned, as to which text is useful and which isnt. i will just leave it as is.

Comment: @corsiKa for that matter, if someone said "attacks?" A'd assume that they're probably the NAP anyway