# Can Disallow prevent me from crewing a vehicle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It is my turn and I have [Veteran Motorist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeteran%20Motorist%5d) and an [Aethersphere Harvester](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAethersphere%20Harvester%5d) on the battlefield.

Entering the declare attackers phase I announce/tap my motorist to crew the harvester. In response my opponent plays [Disallow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisallow%5d) to counter my crewing the harvester.

Does this prevent me from crewing the harvester?

Comment: Slight correction: The Declare Attackers phase is too late to crew your Aethersphere Harvester if you want to attack with it. It isn't a creature, so you can't select it as an attacker (508.1a). The last chance to crew the vehicle is during the Beginning of Combat Step, (507.3). In this, it is important to be careful how you move from your main phase to combat; reason: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28964/if-a-player-goes-to-combat-and-then-activates-an-ability-what-is-the-game-st

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Disallow will prevent you from crewing your vehicle: your vehicle will not become a creature, and the creatures you tapped to pay the crew cost will remain tapped.

From [the comprehensive rules on Crew](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Crew):

> **702.121a** Crew is an activated ability of Vehicle cards. “Crew N” means “Tap any number of untapped creatures you control with total power N or greater: This permanent becomes an artifact creature until end of turn.”

This is an activated ability with a cost of tapping creatures and an effect of turning the vehicle into a creature. It's a legal target of [Disallow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisallow%5d), so we can prevent its effect from resolving.

Note that even despite the crew ability being countered, Veteran Motorist's ability would still trigger (because you tapped it to pay a crew cost), and [the vehicle will still receive +1/+1 until end of turn](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/34318/5573). If you manage to turn the vehicle into a creature later this turn, that +1/+1 will start to apply.

Comment: Worth noting that there is nothing preventing you from using the crew ability again during the same turn if you've got enough untapped creatures. (The ones from the disallowed crewing will still be tapped)

Comment: Very late to the party, but in particular if you have two Veteran Motorists your vehicle will end up with +2/+2 until end of turn.